# Why does this movq instruction work on linux and not osx?

Tags: linux, macos, x86-64

The following assembly code gives an error when running `as` on OSX 10.9.4, but works successfully on Linux (Debian 7.6). In particular, the movq instruction doesn't seem to like the label argument.

```
$ cat test.S
.globl _main
_main:
    movq $_main, %rax
    ret
```

Here is the error:

```
$ as -o test.o test.S 
test.S:3:32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64
test.S:3:cannot do signed 4 byte relocation
```

Changing `$_main` in line 3 to a literal like `$10` works fine.

The code had to be modified in a very minor way to get it to run on Linux - by simply removing the underscores from the labels.

```
$ cat test.S
.globl main
main:
    movq $main, %rax
    ret
```

It's pretty easy to independently verify that the code does work on Linux:

```
$ as -o test.o test.S
$ gcc -o test.out test.o
$ ./test.out
```

Please ignore that the code doesn't really do much of anything, I've intentionally trimmed it down as much as possible to demonstrate the error.

I've looked quite a bit into using LEA (load effective address), but before I make that change I'd like to understand the difference - why does it work on Linux and not OSX?

Comment: +1 well written question with a very good minimal, complete, verifiable code example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct about the `movq` instruction not being able to reference the absolute address. This is in part due to the [**OS X ABI Mach-O**](https://github.com/aidansteele/osx-abi-macho-file-format-reference) format which uses relocatable addressing for symbols.

A Program that is compiled as a position-independent executable (`PIE`) generally cannot reference an absolute virtual address in the same manner as `movq $_main, %rax` does. Instead, [**Global Offset Tables**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/x86_64_code.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005044-SW1) are called upon, which allow position relative code (`PC-rel`) and position-independent code (`PIC`) to extract global symbols at their current absolute address location. Demonstrated below, `GOTPCREL(%rip)`creates an interpretation of `lea rdi, _msg`:

**PC-rel code referencing it's Global Offset Table:**

```
.globl _main
_main:

    movq     _main@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    sub      $8, %rsp
    mov      $0, %rax
    movq     _msg@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
    call     _printf
    add      $8, %rsp
    ret

.cstring
_msg:

    .ascii  "Hello, world\n"
```

**Mac OS X Mach-O Assembler:**

```
$ as -o test.o test.asm
```

**Apple's version of GCC:**

```
$ gcc -o test.out test.o
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./test.out
Hello, world
```

Comment: This is wonderfully helpful, and I'll definitely accept the answer. But, I'm wondering if you can explain what happens on Linux? Though I guess the answer is pretty simple: it uses absolute addressing? However (and maybe I'm confused, and maybe this deserves it's own follow up question), I thought that relocatable addressing was required in and/or fundamental to x86-64.

Comment: The Linux example may appear to be using absolute addressing, however, the instructions such as `$main, %rax` automatically get translated into `GOTPCREL` and utilize its respective Global Offset Table. The Procedure Linkage Table (PLT) — the mechanism which  determines the absolute address of a function at runtime also differs a bit. ELF PLT entries are organized and grouped into chunks identified by their own `plt` section. With Mach-O the PLT is spliced across multiple sections, which are called `stub helpers`, and require an extra step to find a corresponding symbol id.

Comment: The beauty of consistently using `GOTPCREL` for programs intended for both Linux and OS X is that it saves tons of time; for all that needs to be changed is adding underscores to symbols, or removing them. [This example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fa1fe6586589995b35d) demonstrates nearly identical Linux/OS X code using this principle.

Comment: @joshcough:  You never need to use the GOT for accessing your own symbols, just `lea _msg(%rip), %rdi` same as a compiler would use with `-fPIE` or `-fPIC` on Linux.  https://godbolt.org/z/WKPTYv  What you *can't* assume is that `_printf` will be reachable with a `call rel32` because it's in a shared library; that actually needs indirection. The linker will convert `call _printf` into a call through a stub that uses the GOT.  On Linux, `gcc -fno-plt` will use `call   *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)` to bypass that stub  through the PLT, or use the GOT directly to make an indirect call.

Comment: Your answer works, but it's an inefficient and over-complicated way to do things which also creates more work for the dynamic linker to do.  (Filling in those GOT entries at process startup.)  It also misses the chance to explain that x86-64 has good RIP-relative addressing capabilities that makes efficient PIC code possible without much help from the dynamic linker.  I wouldn't recommend anyone ever write their code this way; that's why I downvoted.

Comment: I found this while looking for duplicates for recent questions that make the same mistake.  The whole point of Stack Overflow is to build up a database of useful answers, ideally canonical answers.  Future answers can link them, or we can just close duplicates.  Most of the basics have already been covered over the years, so a lot of new questions can be dealt with by finding a good existing answer.

Comment: Re: efficiency: they're the same code-size and both decode to 1 uop, but the RIP-relative load can miss in cache.  And it wastes 8 bytes (or the whole line) of cache footprint for cache that could be caching something else if you didn't load that data from memory.  It can also cause a dTLB miss -> page walk and stall the CPU for even longer, although the GOT is usually not huge and the page translation would usually stay hot.  (But the GOT would be larger if you waste space in it for every private static data item!).

Comment: And that's besides making the executable larger, with metadata for the symbol name, and the dynamic linker having to fill in the absolute address into the GOT entry every time the program starts.  If you want more info about CPU internals, see https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ and https://agner.org/optimize/.

Comment: Are you talking to me this whole time? Thank you for the optimization information, it's certainly useful. I think you might've misunderstand the intentions of my answer; it was only to show the difference in ABI's and why the mach-o assembly choked on virtual absolute addresses. I mentioned GOT because it's a simple way to demonstrate the difference in elf and mach-o ABI's and a way to overcome coding two flavors of assembly.

Comment: Why not post a gist to your version which compiles for both macho-o and elf (only by needing to change the section prefixes from underscore to periods or vice versa), no compiler options, and a maximum of 10 minutes coding it. I'm curious how terrible the benchmark on mine will be compared to yours. Don't take this comment this wrong way, I'm not trying to pick a fight here, I just want to see firsthand why it's such a big deal.