# Combining c and assembler code

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly, x86-64

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void sum();
    int newAlphabet;
    int main(void)
    {
        sum();
        printf("%d\n",newAlphabet);
    }
```

And this is my assembler code:

```
.globl _sum

_sum:
    movq $1, %rax
    movq %rax, _newAlphabet
    ret
```

I'm trying to call the sum function, from my main function, to set `newAlphabet` equal to 1, but when I compile it (`gcc  -o test assembler.c assembler.s`, compiled on a 64-bit OSX laptop) I get the following errors:

```
32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64

cannot do signed 4 byte relocation

both caused by the line "movq %rax, _newAlphabet"
```

I'm sure I'm making a very basic mistake. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here are the relevant portions of the C code once it has been translated to assembler:

```
.comm   _newAlphabet,4,2
...
movq    _newAlphabet@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `_newAlphabet` in the assembler? Also, I'm pretty sure that `int` is 32-bits on OSX (even in x86-64).

Comment: I was under the possibly mistaken impression that the int newAlphabet from the c code would be recognized by the assembler. If this is wrong, how do I need to go about fixing that? And should i use movl instead?

Comment: I get the same errors, if I use movl or mov with %eax

Comment: @SimonMeans: What if you try `newAlphabet` (i.e. without underscore)? If this does not help I would advice to compile some simple program that use this external variable with `-S` option to see its assembly instructions (that is, to recognize how this variable is referenced).

Comment: It didn't work. Here are the relevant portions of the compiled c code ".comm _newAlphabet,4,2" "movq _newAlphabet@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax"

Comment: Doesn't the assembly code need the equivalent of an "extern" for newAlphabet? To figure this out, make another C program that includes the sum function written in C, and see if you can get that to work. Once it's working have the C compiler output assembly language for the C code with the sum function. You could also consider passing a pointer to newAlphabet as a parameter to the sum function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799551/why-does-this-movq-instruction-work-on-linux-and-not-osx I think it may answer your issue with `mov` instruction (seems to be duplicate of it if I am reading correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OS X uses position-independent executables by default, which means your code can't use constant global addresses for variables.  Instead you'll need to access globals in an IP-relative way.  Just change:

```
movq %rax, _newAlphabet
```

to:

```
mov %eax, _newAlphabet(%rip)
```

and you'll be set (I changed from 64 to 32 bit registers to match `sizeof(int)` on Mac OS X. Note that you also need a `.globl _newAlphabet` in there somewhere.  Here's an example I just made based on your code (note that I initialized `newAlphabet` to prove it works):

example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(void);
int newAlphabet = 2;
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",newAlphabet);
    sum();
    printf("%d\n",newAlphabet);
    return 0;
}
```

assembly.s:

```
.globl _sum
.globl _newAlphabet

_sum:
    movl $1, _newAlphabet(%rip)
    ret
```

Build & run:

```
$ cc -c -o example.o example.c
$ cc -c -o assembly.o assembly.s
$ cc -o example example.o assembly.o
$ ./example
2
1
```